# fscanf not matching properly

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read through a file that looks like this:

```
truck, wanted, 4000
truck, for sale, 2000
microwave, for sale, 2
truck, wanted, 4000
```

but my `fscanf` is returning `1` (should be `3`):

```
fscanf(file,
         "%s, %[^,], %d",
         items[i].type,
         temp,
         &items[i].price)
```

Basically I want to read it like a CSV, first word into first var, second word(s) (either `wanted` or `for sale`) into temp, and the number into the third var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fscanf` does not work like that. When you specify `%s` format specifier, it reads everything till the next whitespace (or end of input). Which means that your first `%s` will read `truck,`, i.e. include the comma into the string it reads. `%s` does not care that in your format string you placed `,` after `%s` and thus kinda "requested" the comma to be left unread. `fscanf` does not support such requests. `fscanf` does not have any advanced lookahead or pattern matching capabilities. It blindly reads as much as requested by the current format specifier. `%s` reads till the next whitespace - that's all it cares about.

If you want to read this as CSV values, you will have to manually guide `fscanf` every step of the way. In this case you can use use `%[^,]` for all string values. Something like this might work

```
fscanf(file,
       "%[^,], %[^,], %d",
       items[i].type,
       temp,
       &items[i].price)
```

If you want to skip any leading whitespace, you can use `" %[^,], %[^,], %d"` format.

Space before `%d` can be omitted, meaning that `"%[^,], %[^,],%d"` is the same as `"%[^,], %[^,], %d"`.